# Access route params within route/ subRoutes object in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Can anybody tell me if there is a way to access the route params directly inside the route objects?, I need to require different components based on the route object.

```
router.map({
  '/dashboard/*': {
    component: Home
  },
  '/dashboard/:module': {
    component: Module,
    subRoutes: {
      '/': {
        component: require('./components/'+this.$route.params.module+'.vue')
      },
      '/:tab': {
        component: require('./components/'+this.$route.params.tab+'.vue')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't require one or another component depending on the route parameters directly in the router configuration. What you can do instead is create a wrapper component that will use a component or another depending on the route parameters, as the route parameters are accessible from any components.

As written in the `vue-router` [documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/1.0/docs/en/route.md):

> The route object will be injected into every component in a vue-router-enabled app as this.$route, and will be updated whenever a route transition is performed.

Every of your components have access to the current route through `this.$route` therefore you could do something like this:

```
<template>
    <component-a v-if="$route.params.param1 === 'a'></component-a>
    <component-b v-if="$route.params.param1 === 'b'></component-b>
</template>
```

Comment: As jeerbl said, you should check parameters on the view. However I'd recommend you using a render function instead of a template

Comment: Thank you, I was asking because I saw something similar in Voie router https://github.com/inca/voie-example/blob/master/spa/states/user/index.js

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the use of `$route.params` inside the route objects. What you can do though, in your vue you can dynamically load different components based on your `$route.params`

```
<component-a v-if="$route.params == 'a'"></component-a>
```